# idiomatic way to combine 'key exists' with 'and if its the right type' parsing toml

Tags: rust, toml

I am parsing this

```
[xxxxx]
drive0={}
drive1={path="xxxx"}
...
```

sometimes there is a path, sometimes not.

I have working code but I am still trying to learn the rust idiomatic way of doing things. Code:

```
for i in 0..8 {
    let drive_name = format!("drive{}", i);
    if dmap.contains_key(&drive_name) {
        if let Some(d) = config[drive_name].as_table() {
            this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true));
            if d.contains_key("path") {
                if let Some(path) = d["path"].as_str() {
                    let file = OpenOptions::new()
                        .read(true)
                        .write(true)
                        .create(true)
                        .open(path)
                        .unwrap();
                    this.units[i].file.replace(file);
                }
            }
        } else {
            this.units.push(Rkunit::new(false));
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that

```
if let Some(path) = d["path"].as_str()
```

(ie without `if d.contains()` line)

would deal with both cases - ie no "path" and "path" isnt string, but it does not. Same with the `contains_key(drive_name)` too.

I tried various guessed at syntaxes to see if I could avoid another nested if and could find one.

So is there a better way or is this as good as it gets. Any other comments on parsing toml welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches here that might be valid. Since your code is quite complex and uses non-std API's, it's hard to see if my change would be useful:

1. Use your general code structure, but combined `.contains` and applying a function the the contained value into the pattern `.get(...).map(...)`. `x.get(y)` returns an Option value, which allows you access to the whole Option API, unlike `x[y]` which would panic if the key doesn't exist.

   ```rust
   if let Some(d) = config.get(&drive_name).map(|c| c.as_table()) {
       this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true);
       if let Some(path) = d.get("path").and_then(String::as_str) {
       }
   } else {
       this.units.push(Rkunit::new(false));
   }
   ```
2. You can use a match statement with some pre-work. I personally prefer this, since it makes the match arms very explicit, but i think it's less idiomatic:

   ```rust
   let drive = config.get(&driver_name); // return an option
   let path = drive.map(|d|.get("path")); // returns an option
   match (drive, path) {
       (Some(d), Some(p)) => {
           this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true));
           let file = OpenOptions::new()
               .read(true)
               .write(true)
               .create(true)
               .open(path)
               .unwrap();
           this.units[i].file.replace(p);
       }
       (Some(d), None) => {
           this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true);
       }
       _ => {
           this.units.push(Rkunit::new(false);
       }
   }
   ```

I think 1. is more idiomatic, but I've certainly seen both and it's probably more a matter of style. Composing Option certainly is idiomatic over contains & access.

Comment: what do you mean by non-std APIs?

Comment: @pm100 non-standard API's: basically using non-std, so I can't test it in rust playground since I don't have access to the API you are using.

Comment: thanks for this, v useful. I did not get that I could do that fancy match on a tuple. But the first one seems easiest for me to follow

Comment: well , I tried to incorporate your #1 and it doesnt compile. I dont see why not. rust complains that the d.get on the third line is wrong. Says that d is an Option<Map>, which i dont get. since the first Some should have 'unoptioned' the config.get. (I fixed the trivial typo in line 2)

Comment: @pm100 it probably depends on what `as_table()` returns. In my example, it assumes that `as_table()` returns some sort of HashMap-like API. e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b4db5826b746f3af701b54a5bd43608 works fine. Check what the API of whatever as_table() returns and use it accordingly in the second if statement.

Comment: as_table returns an Option<Table> depending on whether the item is a table or not

Comment: i got it - it needs and_then  instead of map

Comment: see the answer I posted - ty

Answer (score 0):

Somebody may consider chaining of options more idiomatic, yet it's harder to follow.

```
config.get(&driver_name)
    .or_else(|| {                            // no drive, passing None all the way down
        this.units.push(Rkunit::new(false));
        None
    })
    .and_then(|drive| {                      // having a drive, trying to get a path
        this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true)); 
        drive.as_table().get("path")
    })
    .map(|path| {                            // only having a path, we're doing the thing
        let file = OpenOptions::new()
            .read(true)
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open(path.as_str())             // as_str is there
            .unwrap();
        this.units[i].file.replace(file);
    });
// also "unused Option" warning, because map returns an Option<()>
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman It's there to not use `and_then`, the difference would only be in having to return `Some(())` explicitly

Comment: I would not call this idiomatic. Functional call chains shouldn't really have side effects.

Comment: Well complying with functional idioms comes with a bigger code bloat in this case

Answer (score 0):

based on slight massage of somnium's answer I ended with this. It feels crisper and I got to learn some more idiomatic rust

```
      for i in 0..8 {
            let drive_name = format!("drive{}", i);

            if let Some(drive) = dmap.get(&drive_name).and_then(|x| x.as_table()) {
                this.units.push(Rkunit::new(true));
                if let Some(path) = drive.get("path").and_then(|x| x.as_str()) {
                    let file = OpenOptions::new()
                        .read(true)
                        .write(true)
                        .create(true)
                        .open(path)
                        .unwrap();
                    this.units[i].file.replace(file);
                }
            } else {
                this.units.push(Rkunit::new(false));
            }
        }
```

I am aware that any config errors are silently ignored. But thats what I was after. Probaly shouldnt explode if an illegal path is given though -> Later